# jQuery Waypoints handles the first element with a specified class only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to implement the jQuery Waypoints plugin to add an `.active` class to any element with a `.foo` class as it gets into the viewport:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
  element: $('.foo')[0],
  entered: function(direction) {
    $(this.element).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6mouxnd/

The example above will add the `.active` class to the first `.foo` container only. **How do I make it work for the second and any subsequent `.foo` container as well?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop over every `.foo` and create an Inview for each:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
  new Waypoint.Inview({
    element: this,
    entered: function(direction) {
      $(this.element).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```